# How to load a joomla module in jquery dropdown panel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-plugins, joomla, module

I want to load my top-menu in a dropdown panel. I used this "[**jquery dropdown plugin**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dropdownpanel.shtml)" and it just works great for a html static content. But I'm going to load a joomla position in this panel so it may show a module in the dropdown panel. How can I do this?

Note : please see the plugin page before any new suggestion.

Best regards and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, and using joomla 1.5

Go to module manager and make a copy of say, `Main Menu`

Assign that module copy to a unused position like menu_dropdown

Assign that module copy to appear in all pages

Create a new article which only content is `{load_position menu_dropdown}`
You should have enabled the `Content - Load Module` plugin

Now find the article url, example `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=26` and add `&tmpl=component` at the end.

So that url looks like `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=26&tmpl=component`
this url should be the first parameter to `jkpanel.init`

**NOTE**

You should be careful that the article doesn't show up normally, maybe by archiving it.

Comment: Thank you Dear Cesar,
It works ... but how could I assign a specific css to that contentpane ?

Comment: You could use css cascading to override the style, like #dropdownpanel .contentpane{/* Your rules here */}, etc.